# Encontrar la posición de un guión en una cadena en Wordpress usando get_the_title

Tags: php, wordpress

Qué tal,

Tengo un  problema con un string en **Wordpress**.  Necesito encontrar la posición de un guión dentro de la cadena, concretamente en los nombres de canciones con la siguiente estructura:

**Cantante - Canción**

```
$titulo= get_the_title();
$pos= strpos($titulo , "-");
```

Aunque aquí puse la función **strpos**, ya probé con otras más de strings, y con todas sucede lo mismo, por alguna razón que desconozco, nunca encuentran el guión, pero si cualquier otro caracter o cadena.

Cambié la función `get_the_title` por una cadena, y si funciona, encuentra el guión, el problema es entonces el string que se guarda en la variable `$titulo`, usando esa función de Wordpress.

Necesito hacerlo de forma dinámica, así que debo extraer el título de las entradas de alguna forma, y por lo que veo, `get_the_title` tiene problemas, al imprimir en pantalla funciona bien, al usarla en una variable para buscar el guión no, pero si al buscar cualquier otro caracter o cadena, incluyendo los espacios en blanco.

Es como si el guión que se guarda en la variable, fuera un caracter especial que no reconoce, en teoría no lo encuentra en la cadena, repito, probé con todos los guiones existente e incluso lo copié directamente, nada funciona.

Gracias.

Comment: Encontré la solución, el guión se guarda como código decimal &#8210, estuve haciendo pruebas, y sin querer lo imprimió así,con el código, es curioso porque si imprimo caracteres antes del guión, este aparece como -, pero si la cadena se trunca justo en la zona de guión, empiezan a aparecer los caracteres decimales,  "210 canción".  Saludos.